# IntelliJ ideaVim - timeoutlen with angle bracket <

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

When in insert mode in IntelliJ, typing `<` takes `timeoutlen` time (defaults to 1000ms, which is sane and useful for many other commands; changing `timeoutlen` to 10ms makes `<` basically immediate).

When in insert mode in Vim, typing `<` is immediate.

`:imap <` shows me no results, either in IntelliJ or in Vim.

How can I determine why IntelliJ is delaying this keystroke? How do I fix this?

I have my ~/.ideavimrc symlinked to my ~/.vim/vimrc, but I don't have any plugins installed. I have some custom functions defined that don't seem to do anything, but none of them use the `<` in their mappings.

When I type `imap` in ideavim, I get this:

```
i  <C-Q>       * <Esc>:q!<CR><Tab><Tab>" quit without saving with C-q
i  <C-S>       * <Esc>:wq!<CR><Tab><Tab>" save and exit files with C-s
i  <C-Y>       * <Esc>:set list!<CR>:set number!<CR>i
i  <MiddleMouse> * :set paste<CR><S-Ins>:set nopaste<CR>
```

Comment: Character will appear after timeoutlen seconds or on typing next character. In the original Vim a mapped character is shown over the cursor and put into the document after the timeout, while in IdeaVim nothing visual is happening during the timeout: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-688#focus=streamItem-27-730674-0-0

Comment: While interesting, this does not help with the fact that I don't believe I have any remaps of `<` that should cause this timeout only on `<`.

Comment: Could you check if you have `<` in the output of `:imap`? (without `<` in the command)? It could be the case IdeaVim doesn't parse some Vim special key in mapping commands and since special keys start with `<` it might result in an error.

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh, I do have those, but according to the link that y.bedrov provided, "<expr> mappings are ignored since 0.34." which was 5 years ago.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Could you share all your mappings in your question? So far it's not clear how to reproduce this problem. FYI this is [the source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/81c92cda79ec24ca2626fe1080816ab05532740f/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/helper/StringHelper.java#L150) for parsing Vim mapped keys.

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh added mappings to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that IdeaVim doesn't understand the `<MiddleMouse>` special key from your config and treats it literally as the key sequence `<`, `M`, `i`, ..., `>`.

Feel free to file a bug to the IdeaVim issue tracker to either handle or ignore the `<MiddleMouse>` key.

As a workaround, you can comment out this mapping or put it into a config file that is not sourced from ~/.ideavimrc.